# How to make list cell transparent while dragging SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, view

I have a swiftUI List in one of my app. I had made the list and list cell transparent and everything was working fine. After iOS 16 I started facing issues with transparency of my list. One thing I can't figure out how to make list cell transparent when you drag them for reordering. List cell is transparent initially but when you long press and drag, it becomes white. This behaviour was not there in previous iOS versions. Here is a sample code.

```
struct SampleListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<10) {
                Text("This is item no. \($0)")
                    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
            }
            .onMove(perform: move)
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .background(LinearGradient(colors: [.cyan, .mint, .pink], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
    }
    
    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        //
    }
}
```

Can you help me find a proper way of achieving this ?